# ServiceStack: Change DefaultNoProfileImgUrl

Tags: servicestack

I need to change the profile photo by default, anyone knows how to do it?

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthMetadataProvider.cs

Field is const.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AuthMetadataProvider.DefaultNoProfileImgUrl` has been made static in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/381deea5cf277645bb684537f534a0f7294dd5d4). This change is available from v4.5.5+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks a lot Demis!